# Parsing xml that has the same element name in different levels of the tree

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm having some troubles wrapping my head around how to go about parsing some xml that has a repeated structure and has a lot of repeated variable names.

The xml I'm trying to parse looks something like this:

```
<pages>
  <page id=413419>
  <title>page 1</title>
  <subpages>
    <page id=119>
      <title>page 1.1</title>
      <subpages>
        <page id=13851>
          <title>page 1.1.1</title>
        </page>
        <page id=1551>
          <title>page 1.1.2</title>
        </page>
      </subpages>
    </page>
    <page id=41415>
      <title>page 1.2</title>
      <subpages>
        <page id=0928>
          <title>page 1.2.1</title>
        </page>
        <page id=155661>
          <title>page 1.2.2</title>
        </page>
      </subpages>
    </page>
  </subpages>
 </page>
</pages>
```

My problem is that using something like `$(data).find("page")` gets all the pages and ignores the hierarchy. How can I go about parsing this email while adhering to the xml's structure?

Comment: Can you please describe what kind of result do you like to have in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .children() rather than .find:

```
$(data).children('page')
```

will return all page elements directly 
under the top level element.

Comment: i have one doubt please help me out in parsing the value i want to compare the value with xml value which present in every node and of same name name how i can compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591761/how-to-compare-the-value-with-xml-data

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you want to do with it (and what technology you are prepared to use). This is the kind of XML structure where XSLT really comes into its own.